# Different ssh login directory from user home

Tags: ssh, login, cd-command, home, profile

So, I'm working on a remote server via ssh that I log in and out of dozens of times a day, and I'd like to have bash `cd` to a default directory I've chosen as soon as I login, but I don't actually want to change the user home. Is there any simple way to do that?

To be clear, what I want is to see, say, `~/foo/bar/` when I login, instead of `~/`, and have the option to change the default at will without having to worry about dangerous `usermod` craziness.

It's not important, but it would definitely be convenient.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`file, put this at the end of the file:

```
cd /path/to/your/destination
```

Save the file and log out and log back in, you should be in `/path/to/your/destination`.

---

You could also create an alias on your local account, edit your local `~/.bashrc` and add:

```
alias fastlogin='ssh servername -t "cd /path/to/your/destination; exec bash --login"'
```

Source your file so changes take effect:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now test it by typing `fastlogin` in your terminal.

You require `bash` at the end so the connection doesn't terminate after `cd` executes and `--login` is required so it sources your `~/.bashrc` & `~/.bash_profile` files.

Answer (score 1):

user home is pointed by HOME variable. So - if you want change it - you can change HOME variable in .bashrc, .bash_profile or something. Look:

```
undefine@uml:~$ echo $HOME
/home/undefine
undefine@uml:~$ export HOME=/tmp
undefine@uml:/home/undefine$ cd ~
undefine@uml:~$ pwd
/tmp
```

Comment: But will that cause any trouble with the .ssh directory that holds my private keys? I'd rather use a cd command than risk losing access.

Comment: if you mean authorized_keys - no. .ssh path is defined in sshd_config(AuthorizedKeysFile) and is related to gecos entry. Any changes of HOME variable done after login has no impact to authorization process.